Unable to execute JavaScript based stored procedures on Snowflake via Airflow DAGs
We are experiencing some issues with the 2.5.1 airflow with python snowflake connector 2.9.0.
When trying to execute JavaScript-based stored procedures, we get the below error:

Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.

Here is how the stored procedure handles exceptions
try {
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: “BEGIN TRANSACTION;”} );
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: “COMMIT;”} );
}
catch(err) {
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: “ROLLBACK;”} );
}

Here the DAG task.
create_config_table = f"““call {target_schema}.STORED_PROCEDURE(‘{target_schema}’, ‘{storageIntegration}’,‘S3 URI’);””"

call_CONFIG_DATA_LOAD = SnowflakeOperator(
task_id='call_CONFIG_DATA_LOAD ',
snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id,
database=database_name,
schema=target_schema,
role=admin_role,
warehouse=warehouse,
sql=create_config_table,
dag=dag
)


Take Airflow out of the equation.  What happens when you execute the stored procedure directly in Snowflake?  What are the messages in query history?  You have not provided any detail of your stored procedure, so it is hard to diagnose.
